# Pyserial can read from one serial port on its own, but not when another port is opened?

Tags: python, serial-port

I am trying to use PySerial to read from two serial ports.  One port connects to a PC running Linux.  Another connects to an FPGA.  Both devices stream data over a USB port after they are powered on.  I'm trying this on a Mac.

I've written three different scripts using PySerial.

1. Reads from the port connected to the PC.  With a single device/port defined, I can read data streaming from the PC just fine.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import time
import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports

active_jetson_port='/dev/cu.usbserial-11403'
ac_power_port='/dev/cu.usbserial-A1Z7WN4G'


if __name__ == "__main__":

    searching = True
    

    # Connect to the power switch
    ac_ser =  serial.Serial(port=ac_power_port, baudrate=300,
                       stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_TWO, timeout=1)

    print('Applying power')
    ac_ser.write(b'*001')
    

    print('Starting to look.')
    while searching:
        if len([dev for dev in serial.tools.list_ports.comports()\
               if dev.device == active_jetson_port]) == 1:
            searching = False
            continue
        
        time.sleep(0.1)

    print('My search was successful')

    with serial.Serial(port=active_jetson_port, baudrate=115200,
                       timeout=1) as jet_ser:

        for i in range(100):
            bytes_to_read = jet_ser.inWaiting()
            print("Read string: " + str(jet_ser.read(bytes_to_read)))
            time.sleep(1.0)

    ac_ser.write(b'*002')
    time.sleep(1.0)
    ac_ser.close()
```

2. Reads from the port connected to the FPGA.  With a single device/port defined, I can read data streaming from the FPGA just fine.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import time
import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports

# active_fpga_port='/dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART'
active_fpga_port='/dev/cu.usbserial-12'
ac_power_port='/dev/cu.usbserial-A1Z7WN4G'


if __name__ == "__main__":

    searching = True
    

    # Connect to the power switch
    ac_ser =  serial.Serial(port=ac_power_port, baudrate=300,
                       stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_TWO, timeout=1)

    print('Applying power')
    ac_ser.write(b'*001')

    print('Starting to look.')
    while searching:
        if len([dev for dev in serial.tools.list_ports.comports()\
               if dev.device == active_fpga_port]) == 1:
            searching = False
            continue
        
        time.sleep(0.1)

    print('My search was successful')

    with serial.Serial(port=active_fpga_port, baudrate=115200,
                       timeout=1) as fpga_ser:

        for i in range(100):
            bytes_to_read = fpga_ser.inWaiting()
            print("Read string: " + str(fpga_ser.read(bytes_to_read)))
            time.sleep(1.0)

    ac_ser.write(b'*002')
    time.sleep(1.0)
    ac_ser.close()
```

3. Basically combines the two scripts above.  I've used the same devices/ports that I identified in the two scripts above.  However, with this script, I only see data streaming from the PC.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import time
import serial.tools.list_ports

active_fpga_port='/dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART'
active_jetson_port='/dev/cu.usbserial-11203'
ac_power_port='/dev/cu.usbserial-A1Z7WN4G'

if __name__ == "__main__":

    searching = True

    # Connect to the power switch
    ac_ser =  serial.Serial(port=ac_power_port, baudrate=300,
                       stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_TWO, timeout=1)

    print('Applying power')
    ac_ser.write(b'*001')

    # Search for the FPGA port and the Jetson port
    print('Starting to look.')
    while searching:
        devlist = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
        for dev in devlist:
            print(dev.device)
        print("")
        fpgas = [dev for dev in devlist if dev.device == active_fpga_port]
        jetsons = [dev for dev in devlist if dev.device == active_jetson_port]
  
        if len(fpgas) == 1 and len(jetsons) == 1:
            searching = False
            continue

        time.sleep(0.1)

    print('My search was successful')

    fpga_ser = serial.Serial(port=active_fpga_port, baudrate=115200, timeout=1)
    jet_ser = serial.Serial(port=active_jetson_port, baudrate=115200, timeout=1)

    for i in range(100):
        fpga_bytes = fpga_ser.inWaiting()
        print("Read fpga string: " + str(fpga_ser.read(fpga_bytes)))
        jet_bytes = jet_ser.inWaiting()
        print("Read jet string: " + str(jet_ser.read(jet_bytes)))
        time.sleep(1.0)

    jet_ser.close()
    fpga_ser.close()
    ac_ser.write(b'*002')
    time.sleep(1.0)
    ac_ser.close()
```

The device driver for the port connected to the FPGA is a USB to UART bridge provided by Silicon Labs.  I believe the device driver for the port connected to the PC is provided by Mac OS.

Can anyone explain why I am seeing what I'm seeing?

Thanks,

Jason Mazzotta