# Anyone have experience using teraterm code for serial communication

Tags: serial-port, uart, teraterm

I suspect the question I'm about to ask will be frowned upon but I am curious.

Teraterm seems to be robust when a device is power cycled: https://www.reddit.com/r/embedded/comments/f6hpdn/comment/fi5mhmm/.

I am trying to read the boot-up sequence of a computer through UART over USB.

I've tried LabVIEW and the connection is not robust, when I close and re-open a connection when I power cycle. Python also didn't seem to work: [Pyserial can read from one serial port on its own, but not when another port is opened?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77668591/pyserial-can-read-from-one-serial-port-on-its-own-but-not-when-another-port-is).

but I am going to try combining LabVIEW with Python in different modules.

I'm also interested to try TeraTerm's code.  I've spent a few hours searching through TeraTerm's code: https://teratermproject.github.io/index-en.html
and can't find any files that actually involve opening, closing and reading from a serial connection.

Does anyone have experience using TeraTerm's code for just doing serial communication (i.e. not involving GUI interactions)?